# Android: Передача данных с телефона на ПК

Tags: windows, android, java, c++

Как можно организовать передачу данных с Android- приложения на PC.

Допустим, написал приложение под Android(на java) и нужно по нажатию на кнопку отослать данные на PC, или вообще установить непрерывную передачу...

Я хотел бы сделать через WIFI, но информации не нашел по организации такого дела.., может кто делал когда-то или знает как реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Юра Сучко](/users/14645/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE) в любом деле общения между 2-мя субъектами должен быть некто кто является сервером (от слова сервис) - то есть тем кто предоставляет некие услуги и эти услуги выставляет наружу. Далее должен быть клиент, который как-то соединяется с сервером и получает услугу. В сетевом смысле это обычно сервер, который слушает некий порт. Если это веб сервер то он слушает 80-й порт, почтовый слушает 25-й и т.д. Кроме этого должен быть протокол который понимают оба и сервер и клиент. В случае веб сервера это протокол HTTP, для почты SMTP/POP/IMAP.

Подумайте внимательно кто здесь сервер, а кто клиент (иногда они совпадают как в случае с P2P). Какой протокол они будут использовать (протокол это обычно [стек протоколов](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_stack), на нижнем уровне которого сам физический способ общения, а на верхнем приложение).

Возможна масса вариантов общения телефон<->PC: начиная от СМС и bluetooth, заканчивая NFC и тупым USB шнуром.

Answer (score 2):

А что именно вы не нашли?

Если через вайфай - Вам надо сделать сервер на PC, а с андроид устройства, с помощью сокетов например, общатся.

начните например отсюда: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html